# Puppeteer get innerText of a querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, jquery-selectors, puppeteer

hello I have already a script that's passing through parent elements to get their data, and I'm doing it with queryselector but sometimes the parent has several children that I need. so I should use querySelectorAll but I have a problem getting their innerText, hope for help.

```js
      suggestionText = await page.evaluate(
          (el) => el.querySelector('div.nine.columns.suggestiontext').innerText,
          text
        );
        console.log(suggestionText);
```

example of queryselector but I'm getting only one and I want to get more,(text is the parent).

Comment: with the elements given its impossible to help you, could you show a complete sample (functional)

Comment: I will soon today(on my phone) thanks.

Comment: If I have a way to contact you I will be happy 

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) and retutn an array of texts via [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
suggestionTexts = await page.evaluate(
  (el) => Array.from(
    el.querySelectorAll('div.nine.columns.suggestiontext'),
    div => div.innerText,
  ),
  text,
);
console.log(suggestionTexts);
```